# Reporting Services - Report Model (SDML) reference to Data Source View (DSV)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

We have a ad-hoc reporting projecto where we created several data source views (DSV) and several Report Models (SDML). Frequently we need to change the DSV associated to a particular SDML, but we only found it's reference in one place: the "Data Source View Name" property (availabe through the VS properties pane) of the sdml file.

We found absolutly no reference to it anywhere else, not even in the sdml xml code view. But, strangly enough, VS asks to check out the sdml file when we change that "Data Source View Name" property ... then makes no change to the checked out file.

Finally, when we close the project and reopen it, VS forgets that property setting. This behavior points to some kind of in-memory-only saving location for that setting ...

Are we missing something or does anybody noticed similar behavior?

Thanks.
Bruno Lopes

Answer (score 2):

Look in your ReportModel.smdlproj file (the project file).
View it in notepad rather than double-click, as that will just launch Visual Studio.

In the `<Models>` section you'll find:

```
  <Models>
    <ModelProjectItem>
      <Name>MySmdlName.smdl</Name>
      <FullPath>MySmdlName.smdl</FullPath>
      <DsvName>MyDsvName</DsvName>
    </ModelProjectItem>
  </Models>
```

This is how VS associates the dsv and the smdl files.

Why this association is getting lost when you deploy I don't know, but this may help.

Comment: Does this solution work for sql server 2008 r2? I couldn't locate the <Model> or anything related to the datasource view inside.

Comment: Absolutely unbelievable something like this could happen.  So frustrating!  (Thanks for the answer, btw!)

Answer (score 0):

You are right. I do not know if it is by design or anything else but you can try doing this:

After deploying smdl's to the Report Server, click on Edit in the Model Definition section for a smdl. This downloads the smdl and the xml seems to have the DataSourceView element in it!